# Limiting the setInterval function?

Tags: javascript

```
 function greet(name) {
            console.log('Hello Good Morning ' + name );
        }

        
        // let timeout = setTimeout(greet, 3000 , "Alapottra");
        // console.log(timeout);

        // clearTimeout(timeout);

       

       let interval =  setInterval(greet , 2000 , 'Jhon');
        
       let count = 0 ; 
       if (count < 4){
           console.log(interval);
           count++
       }else{
           clearInterval;
       }
```

How to a limit to the interval function like I want it to run 5 times and then stop , I tried using a while loop as well as for loop but it seems like it has no effect whatsoever

Answer (score 3):

You will want to increment the `count` each time the `greet` function is called.

Then, you clear the interval after the predetermined number of times you want it to run.

You need to pass the `interval` to `clearInterval`.

Here is a working snippet:

```js
let count = 0;
function greet(name) {
  count++;
  console.log('Hello Good Morning ' + name);
  if (count > 4) {
    clearInterval(interval);
  }
}
const interval = setInterval(greet, 2000, 'Jhon');
```

Comment: does storing the interval function inside a variable or const makes it call the funtion?

Comment: It will be triggered automatically (in this case after 2 seconds). Assigning it to a variable isn't necessary, but here we do so so we can call `clearInterval` on it.

Answer (score 2):

do like the following code

```
var counter = 0;
function greet (name) {
    counter++
    console.log('Hello Good Morning ' + name );
    if (counter >= 5)
    {
        clearInterval(interval);
    }
}


let interval =  setInterval(greet , 2000 , 'Jhon');
```

Answer (score 1):

```
let count = 0 ; 
let interval = setInterval(greet , 2000 , 'Jhon');

function greet(name) {
  console.log(count);
  if (count < 4){
    count++;
  } else {
    clearInterval(interval);
  }
  
  console.log('Hello Good Morning ' + name );
}
```

I hope that this will be helpful to you.

Comment: hey i was wondering where did the greet(name) function u made got called ? the question might seem a bit stupid but i am new to javascript

Answer (score 1):

To limit the amount of times `setInterval` fires any given function, simply wrap the `setInterval` function in another function that handles this for you.

Here's a `setFiniteInterval` function I came up with that accepts the basic `setInterval` parameters, but also accepts a paremeter of `tries: number = null` that dictates how many times `setInterval` should run.

In addition, I've also added a `fireImmediately: boolean = false` parameter that can be set to true if you want to fire the function you passed immediately. This is subtracted from the number of tries you set, so setting `tries` to `10` and `fireImmediately` to `true` will result in the function running once immediately and 9 more times in intervals, while setting `tries` to `10` and `fireImmediately` to `false` will result in the function running 10 times in intervals.

The rest of the parameters are primarily to be used in the function itself to clear the interval and set a new one.

```js
let setFiniteInterval = (fn, delay = 1000, tries = null, fireImmediately = false, currentCount = 0, interval) => {
    clearInterval(interval);
    if (tries === currentCount) return;
    if (!currentCount && fireImmediately) fn();
    interval = setInterval(() => {
        tries = fireImmediately ? tries - 1 : tries;
        fn();
        setFiniteInterval(fn, delay, tries, false, ++currentCount, interval);
    }, delay);
};
```

Here's an example of logging "Hello world!" 10 times in 1 second intervals.

```js
setFiniteInterval(() => {
    console.log("Hello world!");
}, 1000, 10);
```